# eJabberd and GTalk no longer federating. Did Google drop support for server-to-server XMPP?

Tags: google, xmpp, ejabberd

Recently GTalk and my local eJabberd installation have stopped talking to each other.
The eJabberd log says the following:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 2014-05-27 18:00:25 ===
I(<0.367.0>:ejabberd_s2s:404) : New s2s connection started <0.368.0>

=INFO REPORT==== 2014-05-27 18:00:25 ===
I(<0.368.0>:ejabberd_s2s_out:1203) : Trying to open s2s connection: slapdogaf.dk -> gmail.com with TLS=true

=INFO REPORT==== 2014-05-27 18:00:26 ===
I(<0.364.0>:ejabberd_listener:281) : (#Port<0.3596>) Accepted connection {{74,125,187,81},61981} -> {{192,168,100,115},5269}

**=INFO REPORT==== 2014-05-27 18:00:26 ===
I(<0.368.0>:ejabberd_s2s_out:365) : Connection established: slapdogaf.dk -> gmail.com with TLS=false**

**=INFO REPORT==== 2014-05-27 18:00:46 ===
I(<0.376.0>:ejabberd_s2s_out:443) : wait for validation: slapdogaf.dk -> gmail.com (closed)**
```

I'm using eJabberd 2.1.11. Any suggestions? Or did Google finally kill XMPP federation for GTalk?

Answer (score 0):

If you enforce encryption (STARTTLS) on your s2s link, you're effectively blocking federation with GTalk. They don't support encrypted S2S.

Answer (score -1):

> Or did Google finally kill XMPP federation for GTalk?

Google announced that they would be disabling federation about a year ago. If they had published a schedule for deprecating federation, I haven't seen it, but I guess it is disabled now, at least for your server's IP.

Comment: They still federate, but don't support TLS, for mysterious reasons.